# Creating a function message in R that tests if the input is a string

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to make a message in my function that tells the user to pass in the argument as a string, that is if they forget the quotation marks then the message should say "use quotation marks" and not "object X not found". Is that possible?

```r
print_name <- function(name){
  if (!is.character(name)){
    stop("Name should be a character")
  }
  else {
    print(name)
  }
}

print_name(david)
#> Error in print_name(david): object 'david' not found

print_name("david")
#> [1] "david"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `tryCatch`

```
print_name <- function(name){
   tryCatch({
     if (is.character(name))
       print(name)
     else
       print("not a character")
    }, error = function(e) {
    stop("Name should be a character - use quotes!")
  })
}
```

and then run the function

```
print_name(david)
```

> Error in value[3L] : Name should be a character - use quotes!

```
print_name("david")
#[1] "david"

print_name(2)
#[1] "not a character"
```

Comment: @David It's a variable to catch the error message. If you print `e$message` in the `error` function you will get the actual error message (in this case `object 'david' not found`) so that you can take actions based on that if required.